# IronPython throw InsufficientMemoryException when using numpy in threads

Tags: c#, python, multithreading, numpy, ironpython

I have some `IronPython` code that being called from within a `C#` application.
This code worked fine until I decided to change one function to run in a thread.
when numpy functions called in a python thread a `InsufficientMemoryException` exception is thrown.
I Searched for solutions but didn't find. can someone explain why it is happening and how can I fix it?

I think this is happening only when I have two threads that use `numpy`

I run code like this:

**C#:**

```cs
_python.functionA(); # _python was created with "Python.CreateEngine()"
_python.functionA(); # twice on purpose
```

**Python:**
my_python_script.py

```py
import threading
import time
import numpy

def blah():    
    print numpy.array([100,100,0])

def functionA():
    t = threading.Timer(0,blah)    
    t.start()
    time.sleep(2)
```

**And I got this Exception:**

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7.1\Lib\threading.py", line 552, in _Thread__bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7.1\Lib\threading.py", line 756, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\workspace\my_python_script.py", line 113, in blah
    print numpy.array([100,100,0])
MemoryError: Exception of type 'System.InsufficientMemoryException' was thrown.
```

Thanks

***UPDATE** 13/07/14*

I get this exception even when I run only one thread and via IronPython interpreter, without the C#:

```
C:\>"c:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7.1\ipy.exe"
IronPython 2.7.1 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.18063
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> execfile(r"c:\workspace\my_python_script.py")
>>> functionA()
>>> Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7.1\Lib\threading.py", line 552, in _Thread__bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7.1\Lib\threading.py", line 756, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "c:\workspace\my_python_script.py", line 6, in blah
    print numpy.array([100,100,0])
MemoryError: Exception of type 'System.InsufficientMemoryException' was thrown.
```

Comment: How many processors do you have?

Comment: I'm not sure right now, it on my work computer. But I believe it is at least dual, maybe quad. Is it important how exactly?

Comment: You might read [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974065) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1stbec.aspx) and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: quad core, and that didn't fixed the problem :(

Comment: Are you sure that `numpy` is thread-safe? And the other libraries used?

Comment: in cpython it works fine. I don't know if it is thread-safe but i doubt that its not. (Im adding an update to the question)

Comment: Are you using the same numpy package for ironpython and cpython, or are you using the ported version of numpy?
http://blog.enthought.com/python/scipy-for-net/#.U8TA_vldVSQ (a bit old, so it may have changed in the past 3 years)

Comment: @ilmarinen I use different versions. https://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumPy%20and%20SciPy%20for%20.Net

Answer (score 2):

I believe that numpy is not thread-safe. I had a similar problem where using `np.asarray()` with threading would crash my program. It seems that the way that numpy's `array` function builds the array is not thread-safe. The way around this I found was to use `np.fromiter()` instead. Apparently, it is thread safe. It is slightly slower, which makes since if it is not using threading, but it works. Try putting your data into a list (or some other iterable data structure) and using `np.fromiter()` to convert it to a numpy array.

Also, just so you know, it actually runs fine on my computer so it could just be that you don't have enough memory to handle threading (or at least not when using numpy).

Comment: I expected for a solution to this problem and not a workaround so I don't accept this answer yet (maybe solutions will come later).
However, It might be that there is no better solution and your answer is the best so far, so you got the bounty